# Many many downloads causes Request has timed out error with OperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, nsoperationqueue

I need to make around 278 calls to the server and it seems to work for the first 50-100 or so but all the calls after are getting Request has timed out errors. I'm using an OperationQueue. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or tell me how I can do this properly and efficiently?  I've already tried adding waitUntilFinished, setting maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 and using a semaphore, which just freezes the app. If there is another way, I'd love to hear it.

```
for ID in IDs {
     guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + APIurl.kURL + "/" + ID) else {
         return
     }

     if let headers = getHeaders() {
          let operationQueue: OperationQueue = OperationQueue()

          let operation1 = BlockOperation() {
                RequestManager().makeRequest(withURL: url, headers: headers) { (response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error downloading \(String(describing: url))")
                        print("errorDesc  \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    }
                    guard let results = response else {
                        return
                    }
                    print("downloaded \(url)")
                    // save to core data
                }
          }
          operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
        }
    }
}
```

and RequestManager is the call using AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON

```
func makeRequest(withURL url:URL, headers: [String:String], completion: @escaping RequestCompletion) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        guard response.result.error == nil, response.result.value != nil else {
            completion(nil, response.result.error)
            return
        }

        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:
            if let resultValue = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(resultValue)
                completion(json, nil)
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error - > \n    \(error.localizedDescription) \n")
            completion(nil, error)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the server thinks you are a DoS attack and is shutting you down. And rightly so.